# How do I prove that that 91 is/is not a pseudoprime to base 2

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I know that Fermat Pseudoprime formula is $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$ c
but in this case $p$ is not prime.

How do I prove that  that $91$ is/is not a pseudoprime to base $2$.

Answer (score 0):

$91$ is not prime , but  $91=7*13$. Moreover,  $$  2^{90}= 2^{6*15}=64^{15} \equiv (-1)^{15} \equiv -1 \mod{13} $$
since  $13 *5 =65$. 
Hence  $13 \nmid 2^{91-1 }-1$  as  $ 13 \nmid 2^{91-1 }+1 $ and  so  $91 \nmid 2^{91-1 }  $. Therefore  $91$ is not Fermat Pseudoprime of base  2.